# Service Fabric locking and timeout

Tags: multithreading, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I'm dealing with a situation where multiple threads are accessing this method

```
using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
  var item = await reliableDictioanary.GetAsync(tx, key);
  ... // Do work on a copy of item
  await reliableDictioanary.SetAsync(tx, key, item);
  await tx.CommitAsync();
}
```

Single threading this works well, but when I try accessing the dictionary this way using multiple threads I encounter a `System.TimeOutException`.

The only way I've been able to get around it is to use `LockMode.Update` on the `GetAsync(...)` method. Has anyone here experienced something like this?

I'm wondering if there is a way to read with snapshot isolation, which would allow a read with no lock on it, as opposed to a read with a shared lock on the record.

I've tried doing this with both a shared transaction as shown above as well as individual transactions for the get and the set. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default lock when reading, is a shared lock. (caused by `GetAsync`) 
If you want to write, you need an exclusive lock. You can't get it if shared locks exist.

Getting the first lock as an update lock prevents this, like you noticed.

Snapshot isolation happens when enumerating records, which you're not doing with `GetAsync`.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-transactions-locks).